# Questions on Hartshorne II.8.4(b)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have some questions about Exercise 8.4 (b) of Hartshorne:

> Let $Y$ be a closed subscheme of $\mathbf{P}_k^n$.  If $Y$ is a complete intersection of codimension $r$ in $\mathbf{P}_k^n$ (i.e. the homogeneous ideal $I_Y$ of $Y$ in $S=k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ can be generated by $r$ elements), and if $Y$ is normal, then $Y$ is projectively normal.

I probably know how to solve this question, but there are some details I cannot solve:

Step 1: $Y$ is projectively normal $\Leftrightarrow$ $S(Y)=S/I_Y$ is an integrally closed domain $\stackrel{(*)}\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall p\in \operatorname{Spec}S(Y)$, $S(Y)_p$ is an integrally closed domain $\Leftrightarrow$ $\operatorname{Spec}S(Y)$ is normal.

Step 2: Since the affine cone $C(Y)=\operatorname{Spec}S(Y)$ is a locally complete intersection subscheme of $\mathbf{A}_k^{n+1}$, proposition 8.23 shows that $C(Y)$ is normal if and only it is regular in codimension 1.  The normality of $Y$ implies that it is regular in codimension 1, (**) which implies that $C(Y)$ is regular in codimension 1.

**My questions:**

1. (*) holds when $S(Y)$ is an integral domain, but in our case, the homogeneous ideal $I$ of $Y$ may not be a prime ideal.  Can we show that it is an integral domain by the assumption that $\operatorname{Proj} S(Y)$ is normal?
2. I do not know how to prove (**) since there are some inhomogeneous prime ideals of $S(Y)$.

Comment: The assumption alone that $Y$ is normal is not enough for irreducibility: If $Y$ is the union of two disjoint lines in $\mathbf P^3$, then it is normal, but not irreducible. This can happen because normality is a local property. Accordingly $I_Y$ is not a prime ideal.

Comment: @red_trumpet You are right, we also need the fact that $Y$ is a complete intersection to imply $I_Y$ is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it slightly differently, bypassing some of your trouble spots.

From (a), $I_Y$ is generated by $r$ elements, thus $I_{C(Y)}\subset k[\Bbb A^{n+1}]$ is also generated by $r$ elements and so $C(Y)$ is a complete intersection. As $Y$ is a complete intersection and normal, it's singular set is codimension at least 2 by proposition II.8.23(b). But by the Jacobian criteria, the singular set of $C(Y)$ is the cone on the singular set of $Y$ (potentially with the origin thrown in), so the singular set of $C(Y)$ is of codimension at least 2 and by another application of proposition II.8.23(b), $C(Y)$ is normal and hence $Y$ is projectively normal.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain my question 1?  In step 1 of my proof, I think we need the condition that $S(Y)$ is an integral domain.

Comment: I don't think that's going to lead you to a proof without doing more work (for instance, you'd have to connect normal + complete intersection to get connectedness of $Y$ as mentioned in the comments on the question), and I'd rather not do that given that I wrote a pretty quick solution here which avoids all that work.

Comment: The last sentence in your answer claims that we can imply that $Y$ is projectively normal by the fact that $C(Y)$ is normal.  I don't think it is obvious due to (*) in my step 1.

Comment: $C(Y)$ is normal, $C(Y)$ is connected (all irreducible components must pass through the origin), so $C(Y)$ is integral. You're trying to declare that $S(Y)$ must be a domain too early - that's something you want to do at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much! That step seems meaningless but it does bother me a lot.